# Applying mean to a list of data frames, using factors

Tags: r, dplyr

```
library(plyr)
#Creating Reproducible Data#
set.seed(4)
UF <- c("North", "South", "West", "East","North", "South", "West", "East","North", "South", "West", "East")
Gender <- c("Man", "Woman", "Man", "Woman","Man", "Woman", "Man", "Woman","Man", "Woman", "Man", "Woman")
Wage1 <- lapply(1,function(x){sample(1:150,12,replace = T)})
Wage2 <- lapply(1,function(x){sample(1:150,12,replace = T)})
Wage3 <- lapply(1,function(x){sample(1:150,12,replace = T)})
test.frame1 <- data.frame(UF, Gender, Wage1)
test.frame2 <- data.frame(UF, Gender, Wage2)
test.frame3 <- data.frame(UF, Gender, Wage3)
names(test.frame1)[3] <- 'Wage'
names(test.frame2)[3] <- 'Wage'
names(test.frame3)[3] <- 'Wage'

data.list <- list(test.frame1, test.frame2, test.frame3)

#I'm trying to take the mean value of Woman's wage for each UF#

MediumWage <-lapply(data.list, function(x){
  test <- plyr::dlply(x, "UF", function(x) mean(x,Wage[data.list$Gender == "Woman"]))
})
```

So, in theory, I should have something like:

[image]

But running the lapply code just gives me NAs

Answer (score 1):

Your `plyr` code has a few issues.

- You use `function(x)` where `x` is a group inside a data frame, inside a `function(x)` where `x` is the whole data frame-- use different object names so there's no confusion which `x` is which.
- You iterate over different list items, but use `data.list$V2007` (which doesn't exist in your sample data) as a constant. And you're testing if `data.list$V2007 == "Woman"`, when presumably you need to test if the `Gender` column is `"Woman"`

I think these issues can be fixed like this:

```
MediumWage <-lapply(data.list, function(x){
  plyr::dlply(x, "UF", function(y) mean(y$Wage[y$Gender == "Woman"]))
})
```

I find this list result unwieldy. Here's how I would do this in `dplyr`:

```
lapply(data.list, function(x) {
  x %>% filter(Gender == "Woman") %>%
    group_by(UF) %>%
    summarize(mean_wage = mean(Wage))
})
# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 2 × 2
#   UF    mean_wage
#   <chr>     <dbl>
# 1 East       72.3
# 2 South      77.3
# 
# [[2]]
# # A tibble: 2 × 2
#   UF    mean_wage
#   <chr>     <dbl>
# 1 East       69.7
# 2 South     121. 
# 
# [[3]]
# # A tibble: 2 × 2
#   UF    mean_wage
#   <chr>     <dbl>
# 1 East      109. 
# 2 South      50.3
```

But really I would probably name the input list with a meaningful ID and combine it into one data frame and do a single grouped mean. Based on the "V2007", I will assume each list item is a different year, so something like this:

```
names(data.list) = 2007:2009 ## whatever your real years are
data.list %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "year") %>%
  filter(Gender == "Woman") %>%
  group_by(year, UF) %>%
  summarize(Mean_Wage = mean(Wage))
#  year  UF    Mean_Wage
#   <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
# 1 2007  East       72.3
# 2 2007  South      77.3
# 3 2008  East       69.7
# 4 2008  South     121. 
# 5 2009  East      109. 
# 6 2009  South      50.3
```

Comment: Oh im sorry. In my original data frame, V2007 = Gender. Also, each dataframe is supposed to be a year. So, for example, frame 1 = y1, frame 2 = y2, and so on. Im using a list of dataframes because thats how i'm running(succesfully) regressions for them. I couldn't change it for mean tho

Comment: Also, your code only gives me results for East and South, and I`d need it for all UFs! No clue on how to fix it either

Answer (score 0):

Not clear if you want separate means for each `df`, or a grand mean by `UF` across all the `df`.

[1] Separate means:

```
library(data.table)
lapply(data.list, function(x) setDT(x)[Gender=='Woman', .(Wage=mean(Wage)), by=.(UF)])
```

[2] Grand mean:

```
rbindlist(data.list)[Gender=='Woman', .(Wage=mean(Wage)), by=.(UF)]
```

You see only South and East in the result because, in your MRE, all the Women are in South and East.